# Use a Robotis OpenCM9.04 board to control a Trutlebot arm

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, turtlebot, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot arm, but instead of the ArtiboX board, I bought the OpenCM9.04-B, and I'm wondering how to use it to control the arm in ROS without doing all the work from scratch. To my knowledge, there's nothing like the arbotix stack for the OpenCM9.04. So to integrate it on ROS, I should somehow replicate the arbotix stack changing the arduino code to match the Robotis API, right? That's what I'm trying now, following a recommendation I received on [trossen robotics forum](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com/showthread.php?6887-Reuse-arbotix-ROS-stack-for-a-Robotis-OpenCM9-04-B-control-board&p=63784&posted=1#post63784), but its not easy for me, as I have few experience on microcontrolers.

Can someone think in a easier way, or is someone doing the same job? Thank you a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156821/use-a-robotis-opencm9.04-board-to-control-a-trutlebot-arm/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Time to answer to myself... maybe can be useful for someone else.

Yes, it's possible and easy. I just needed to flash a slightly modified version of the [pypose](https://code.google.com/p/arbotix/wiki/PyPose) firmware and arbotix_ros works out of the box for controlling Dynamixel servos (to read sensors it must be slightly hacked). I didn't publish the code, as nobody else seems to be using the OpenCM9.04 with ROS, but I'll happily do if someone needs it.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavi.hmd](https://answers.ros.org/users/21021/pavi.hmd/) on 2014-12-04**:
sir, i am using the opencm9.04b board.it would be very helpful if you publish the code. And can you brief about how you uploaded the code to opencm9.04b? like did you use the arduino IDE or OpenCm provided by ROBOTIS.
Thank you...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-12-05**:
Hi, here you have the firmware I use plus instructions on how to flash it:
https://github.com/corot/thorp/tree/master/thorp_boards
I use the OpenCm from Robotis, but note that the latest version doesn't work; download the one from the link in the README